# Диалог выбора папки в Android

Tags: android

Добрый день , подскажите как из приложения вызвать диалог выбора папки , то есть чтобы в диалоге можно было передвигаться по папкам , а затем нажать ок и диалог вернул бы путь выбранной папки. 
Искал подобное на просторах , но не нашел , чтобы с навигацией было . 
Буду очень благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот как я сделал для себя.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class open_dir extends Activity{
ListView list_dir;
TextView textPath;
Context _context;
int select_id_list = -1;
String path = "/";

ArrayList<String> ArrayDir = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    _context = this;
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.open_dir);

    list_dir = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_dir);
    textPath = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textPath);

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, ArrayDir);
    list_dir.setAdapter(adapter);

    update_list_dir();

    list_dir.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
              select_id_list = (int)id;
              update_list_dir();
          }
        });

}

public void onClickBack(View view)  
{
        path = (new File(path)).getParent();
        update_list_dir();
}

public void onClickGo(View view)  
{
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("url", path);
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
    finish();
}

private void update_list_dir(){
    if(select_id_list != -1) path = path + ArrayDir.get(select_id_list) + "/";
    select_id_list = -1;
    ArrayDir.clear();
    File[] files = new File(path).listFiles();
    for ( File aFile : files ){
         if ( aFile.isDirectory() ) {
             if(dir_opened(aFile.getPath())){
                 ArrayDir.add(aFile.getName());
             }
         }
    }

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    textPath.setText(path);     
}

private boolean dir_opened(String url){
    try{
        File[] files = new File(url).listFiles();
        for ( @SuppressWarnings("unused") File aFile : files ){
        }
        return true;
    } catch(Exception e){
        return false;
    }
}
```

Лейаут:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textPath"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_dir"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="399dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </ListView>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/back"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="onClickBack"
                android:text="@string/open_back" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/go"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:onClick="onClickGo"
                android:text="@string/open_go" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Используеться просто.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, open_dir.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

И обработчик:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        if (data == null) {return;}
        String url = data.getStringExtra("url");
    }
```

Comment: СУПЕР !!! Спасибо большое !!!

Comment: У Вас есть небольшой недочет , как обычно NullPointerException. 
При нажатии кнопки назад в корневой директории приложение крашится .
Переделал на быструю руку. Желательно вообще класс чуть доработать , переменная path как член класса может вызвать некоторые проблемы. 
Вот методы.

Comment: private void update_list_dir(){
        if(select_id_list != -1) {
            path = path + ArrayDir.get(select_id_list) + "/";
        }
        select_id_list = -1;
        ArrayDir.clear();

        File[] files = new File(path).listFiles();
        if (files==null) {

         files =new File("/").listFiles();
            path ="/";
        }
...........}

Comment: public void onClickBack(View view) {
        String tmp = (new File(path)).getParent();
        if (tmp != null) {
            if (!tmp.equals("/")) {
                path = tmp + "/";
            } else {
                path = tmp;
            }
            update_list_dir();

        }
       
    }

Answer (score 1):

[ExFilePicker](https://github.com/bartwell/ExFilePicker)

[aFileChooser](https://github.com/iPaulPro/aFileChooser)

Answer (score 0):

На сколько представляю, нету такого в андроиде. Самому писать надо или гуглить решения.